# Cordova plugin problems CordovaError: Version of installed plugin: "cordova-plugin-file@4.3.3" does not satisfy dependency plugin requirement

Tags: cordova

I'm having a nightmare with Cordova plugins.

> Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-file-transfer': CordovaError:
>   Version of installed plugin: "cordova-plugin-file@4.3.3" does not
>   satisfy dependency plugin requirement "cordova-plugin-file@>=5.0.0".
>   Try --force to use installed plugin as dependency.

Dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "android": "0.0.8",
    "com.rjfun.cordova.httpd": "https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-httpd.git",
    "cordova-android": "^6.3.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^5.0.4",
    "cordova-media-with-compression": "~2.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "~1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "~5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file-downloader": "^0.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file-md5": "^0.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-fullscreen": "~1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-insomnia": "git+https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin.git",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-speechrecognition": "~1.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-webserver": "git+https://github.com/bykof/cordova-plugin-webserver.git",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "~1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-zip": "^3.1.0",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "~2.3.3"
  }
```

Config.xml

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-fullscreen" spec="~1.1.0" />
<plugin name="com.rjfun.cordova.httpd" spec="https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-httpd.git" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" spec="~1.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-media-with-compression" spec="~2.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-downloader" spec="^0.3.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~5.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="^1.7.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-insomnia" spec="https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin.git" />
<plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="~2.3.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-speechrecognition" spec="~1.1.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-webserver" spec="https://github.com/bykof/cordova-plugin-webserver.git" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.3" />
```

I've tried anything I can to upgrade the plugin, removing it, adding it  -clearing out all the plugins etc etc.

Nothing is fixing this.

How do I get past this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it seems that your version of plugin-flie is ahead of file transfer try doing this (ionic 3)

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
npm install --save @ionic-native/file@4.3.3

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer --force
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer@4.3.3
```